# Find if dict values are disproportionate

Tags: python

I have a python dict like this:

```
{'0': 25, '1': 35, '10': 29, '11': 28}
```

The keys are ids, and the value is a count.

How would I find if this dictionary has disproportionate values?
This dict will be disproportionate because id `29` has a count of `186` which is vastly greater than all other values in the dict.

I thought about finding the average mean value and comparing each value to that average value, but is there a more efficient and powerful way of doing this?

Comment: What exactly counts as "disproportionate"?

Comment: This isn't really a Python question, it's a maths or stats question. This subject is anomaly detection. A simple way to do it is calculate z-scores and only keep the values with large negative or large positive z-scores. This is easy with `pandas`, I wouldn't stay in pure Python.

Comment: As it is, this is not really a defined problem. What counts as *vastly greater*? One way to think about it, if these values are meant to be more or less normally distributed, is to see if any of your values are more than 2 or 3 standard deviations from the mean of values...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what I would do.

```
values = d.values()
avg = sum(values)/len(values)
disproportionate_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if abs(v - avg) > some_threshold]
```

The code itself is simple; the only real question is what precisely you mean by "disproportionate"; here I've gone with a simple check that it is a certain distance from the average.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {'0': 25, '1': 35, '10': 29, '11': 28,
       '12': 17, '13': 33, '14': 31, '15': 25,
       '16': 30, '17': 38, '18': 26, '19': 26,
       '2': 20, '20': 31, '21': 29, '22': 22,
       '23': 32, '24': 32, '25': 27, '26': 27,
       '27': 28, '28': 23, '29': 186, '3': 26,
       '4': 30, '5': 27, '6': 28, '7': 34,
       '8': 32, '9': 38}
values = data.values()
avg = sum(values)/len(values)
disproportionate_data = {key:val for key,val in data.iteritems() if val > threshold+avg}
```

For threshold = 20: {'29': 186}

You can set any positive threshold value. It will give you those key:value pairs which are outliers. I hope that's what you need.